# Образование глагола.

Tags: глаголы

Какой глагол образован от слова "чуткий"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что ***родственными*** "чуткий" можно считать глаголы "чуять", "чувствовать", но ни как ***не образованными*** от этого прилагательного.

Answer (score 1):

А еще "родственник"-наречие ЧУТЬ (из др.-русского инфинитива ЧУТИ....

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, что от этого слова нельзя образовать никакой глагол - ни с помощью приставки, ни с помощью суффикса))